# Counting number of rows in dataframe where one column is the max value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to get the number of rows of a dataframe where A=max(A,B) and B=max(A,B). So for example, given the dataframe below, I'd like to get 2 for the count of rows where B=max(A,B). and 1 for the count of rows where A=max(A,B)

```
A | B
-------
1 | 5
-------
2 | 10
-------
7 | 1

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 7], 'B': [5, 10, 1]})
```

I've looked around for solutions but haven't found a clean way to do this

Comment: Can A and B be equal? Then you'd count 1 for each?

Answer (score 3):

You can compute the [`max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.max.html) per row and broadcast the comparison using [`eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html), then aggregate with [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html):

```
out = df.eq(df.max(axis=1), axis=0).sum()
```

Output:

```
A    1
B    2
dtype: int64
```

Intermediate:

```
# df.eq(df.max(axis=1), axis=0)

       A      B
0  False   True
1  False   True
2   True  False
```

##### duplicated values

If you have equal values, like in this example:

```
   A   B
0  1   5
1  2  10
2  7   1
3  5   5
```

The the equal rows would be counted for both.

```
A    2
B    3
dtype: int64
```

If you only want to count the unique `max`, then [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) the non unique ones:

```
tmp = df.eq(df.max(axis=1), axis=0)

out = tmp.mask(tmp.sum(axis=1)>1, False).sum()
```

Or using [`logical_and`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html):

```
tmp = df.eq(df.max(axis=1), axis=0)
out = np.logical_and(tmp, tmp.sum(axis=1).le(1).to_numpy()[:,None]).sum()
```

Output:

```
A    1
B    2
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do it this way:

```
df.idxmax(axis=1).value_counts()
```

Output:

```
B    2
A    1
dtype: int64
```

`df.idmax` only fines the first occurrence of a max value, therefore, if you have duplicates you need to use @mozway's solution.

Comment: Smart hacky one, but this would give priority to one value in case of equality (I asked OP what should happen in this case) ;)

Comment: Just typing that up in the solution.  Thanks for educating the masses.

Comment: That's a great way to generalize multiple comparisons if you need to define priorities (get max but if equal then pick A over B, B over C, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

One option, assuming you're only working with two columns, is to use a simple equality check:

```
sum(df['A'] >= df['B']) # 1

sum(df['A'] <= df['B']) # 2
```

Another option, if you have more, is something like this:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x['A'] == max(x), axis = 1).sum()
```

Comment: For the second approach you shouldn't use `apply`, you can easily vectorize ;)

Comment: @mozway thanks for the tip! :-) it's so hard (both with Python and R) to know when one is using a vectorised function, and when one is not :') especially when numpy.vectorize does nothing

Comment: Most of the time, if you just do numerical operations (comparison, addition, logical) you can vectorize.

Comment: ah, and df.apply() is by nature not vectorised @mozway

Comment: I wish things were more obvious when they are vectorised (e.g. if they were bright pink) hahaha